# Unable to patch anything in this entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, patch

I'm doing an ASP.NET Web API project and have encountered strange behavior here, since I'm unable to patch anything from this entity.

It returns a http 204 status code, but without any changes in database. I just can't tell why.

Here is relevant code:

`UsersController.cs`:

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public IActionResult Patch(int id,
                           [FromBody] PatchUserDTO dto,
                           [FromServices] PatchUserValidator validator)
{
    var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var result = validator.Validate(dto);

    if (!result.IsValid)
    {
        return UnprocessableEntity();
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.Username))
    {
        user.Username = dto.Username;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.FirstName))
    {
        user.FirstName = dto.FirstName;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.LastName))
    {
        user.LastName = dto.LastName;
    }

    if (dto.Sex.HasValue)
    {
        user.Sex = (char)dto.Sex;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.EmailAddress))
    {
        user.EmailAddress = dto.EmailAddress;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.HomeAddress))
    {
        user.HomeAddress = dto.HomeAddress;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.Password))
    {
        user.Password = HashHelpers.HashToSHA512(dto.Password);
    }

    if (dto.RoleID.HasValue)
    {
        user.RoleID = (int)dto.RoleID;
    }

    //_context.Entry(user).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return NoContent();
}
```

`PatchUserValidator.cs`:

```
public class PatchUserValidator : AbstractValidator<PatchUserDTO>
{
    public PatchUserValidator(MiniactionContext context)
    {
        RuleLevelCascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;
        RuleFor(x => x.Username)
                .Must((dto, username) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || !context.Users.Any(u => u.Username == username))
                .WithMessage("Username has to be unique or nothing if not modifying!");
        RuleFor(x => x.Sex)
                .Must(x => !x.HasValue || (char)x == 'M' || (char)x == 'F')
                .WithMessage("Sex has to be male, female or nothing if not modifying!");
        RuleFor(x => x.EmailAddress)
                .EmailAddress()
                .WithMessage("Invalid email address.")
                .Must(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) || !context.Users.Any(u => u.EmailAddress == x))
                .WithMessage("Email address has to be unique or nothing if not modifying!");
        RuleFor(x => x.Password)
                .Must(password => string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) || Regex.IsMatch(password, "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,}$"))
                .WithMessage("Password has to be have at least one number, one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, and be at least 4 characters long or be nothing if not modifying.");
        RuleFor(x => x.RoleID)
                .Must(x => !x.HasValue || context.Roles.Any(r => r.ID == (int)x))
                .WithMessage("Role has to exist or to be nothing if not modifying!");
    }
}
```